# BlurDataURL with Plaiceholder in NextJS and Storyblok

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-image, storyblok

Anybody know how to use plaiceholder with NextJS and Storyblok?
I'm trying to implement it in  component to use placeholder="blur" and blurDataURL because I had dynamic image but everytime it gave me error.